# Create web notification with timeout

Tags: typescript, datejs, web-notifications

How do I create a TypeScript web notification with a set timeout?

I created the following code but doesn't work in closing the notification before the default timeout:

```
export function createNotification(title: string, body: string) {
    let now: Date = new Date(Date.now());
    let date = now.add(5).seconds();

    let options = {
        body: body,
        requireInteraction: false,
        timestamp: date
    };
    new Notification(title, options);
}
```

As a test I want to create a notification in TypeScript which lasts five seconds, overriding the browsers default behaviour. I can't see any further options listed in the TypeScript typings file which would be helpful to me:

[image: ES2017 Notification Options]

I'm using for developing and testing this software using Chrome, although I use Firefox as my main browser. So any solutions which works correctly in Chrome, but doesn't include hacks or browser specific code would be fine.

Comment: " but doesn't work in closing the notification before the default timeout:" can you be clearer about what are you expecting as behavior for your class ?

Comment: `now.add()` ... doesnt exist on the Date class. Have you considered using something like momentjs for your date manipulations. The moment equivalent would be `moment().add(5, 'seconds')`.

Comment: Also, web notifications are buggy in Firefox: https://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications ("Firefox notifications disappear after a few seconds")

Comment: @DarkNeuron I'm using DateJS typings

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try Notification.close() ?

```
function spawnNotification(theBody,theIcon,theTitle) {
  var options = {
      body: theBody,
      icon: theIcon
  }

  var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
  setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), 4000);
}
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/close